# Teamcity is unable to download the NuGet Selenium WebDriver package

Tags: c#, selenium, continuous-integration, nuget, teamcity

We are attempting to run our Selenium tests on TeamCity after build.

It appears as though the Selenium.WebDriver reference isn't downloaded by TeamCity. Here's the output of our build:

```
SeleniumTests.cs(3, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OpenQA' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
SeleniumTests.cs(4, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OpenQA' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
SeleniumTests.cs(11, 9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PhantomJSDriver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Each of these references are inside the Selenium.WebDriver package.

All of the other NuGet references: NUnit.Runners and NUnit are resolved by TeamCity perfectly fine (NuGet package restore appears to be working).

NuGet will automatically resolve the packages and run the tests fine on my local computer.

I tried removing the Selenium.WebDriver NuGet package from the project. This causes the **exact same error**, so it appears as though the package is never downloaded.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Update:** the Seleinum WebDriver package has 2 files: a dll and an xml. TeamCity was downloading the xml but not the dll. I manually copied the dll from my computer into the packages folder on the TeamCity server and our tests ran. I'll leave this open for anyone to answer why only some of the files were downloaded with NuGet.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229182/msbuild-nuget-targets-nuget-exe-unable-to-read-package-from-path-blah-nupkg/30254180#30254180)?

Comment: Are you sure your package restore step is making use of the correct packages.config where Selenium WebDriver is referenced?

Comment: Aditya Santoso, it definitely is because it downloaded the xml file. See the update in the OP.